# C# Создание кнопок в боте телеграм

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Помогите пожалуйста, написать код для создания кнопок в боте телеграм.

[image: Вот такие ошибки в кодах, которые нахожу в интернете.]

[image: Вот такие ошибки в кодах, которые нахожу в интернете.]

Comment: Это ошибки если с интернета брать код.

Comment: Советую вам для начала взять простой проект, калькулятор например и изучить основы C#, тогда у вас таких вопросов, я думаю, не возникнет. А бот, это довольно трудная для новичка задача.

Comment: Покажите свой код. Укажите версию библиотеки (а то в сети встречается старый код, там теперь немного иначе всё).

Answer (score 0):

Ну вообще в текущей (14той) версии библиотеки работает так:

```
var text = "some text";

var ikm = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
{
    new[]
    {
        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("создать", "myCommand1"),
    },
    new[]
    {
        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData("скрыть", "myCommand2"),
    },
});

await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(Update.Message.Chat.Id, text, replyMarkup: ikm, cancellationToken: CancellationToken);
```

Это для инлайн кнопок, самый ходовой пример. Ещё есть варианты типа `InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl()` - смотрите на автокомплите что предлагает и документацию.

Comment: Опять таки эти ошибки, а если using Telegram.Bot.Types это подключить уже другая ошибка связана с записей у файл.

Comment: @NinjaKenny Вам разные люди дают абсолютно рабочий код из своих реальных проектов, а вот вы свой не показываете - даже когда вас просят внести правки в свой вопрос и написать, как вы подключаете библиотеку (я - через nuget), какую версию вы используете и так далее. Пока вы эту информацию не предоставите - помочь вам будет крайне сложно.

Answer (score 0):

Если v13.4 то так (Вырезка из моего проекта):

```
public static Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardMarkup Category = new Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardMarkup
{
    InlineKeyboard = new[]
 {
            new[]{new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Птица ", "call_category ptiza 0"), new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Хлеб ", "call_category hleb 0") },
            new[]{new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Мясо ", "call_category myaso 0"), new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Молоко ", "call_category moloko 0") },
            new[]{new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Молочка ", "call_category moloko-i-syr 0"), new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Рыба ", "call_category ryba 0") },
            new[]{new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Мёд/варенье ", "call_category varene-mjod 0"), new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Мясные изделия ", "call_category mjasnye-izdelija 0") },
            new[]{new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Фрукты и овощи ", "call_category frukty-i-ovoshhi 0"), new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Полуфабрикаты ", "call_category polufabrikaty 0") },
            new[]{new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Напитки ", "call_category napitki 0"), new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("⚱️ Соусы ", "call_category sousy 0") },
            new[]{new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Кондитерка ", "call_category konditerka 0"), new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Специи ", "call_category specii 0") },
            new[]{new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Сухофрукты ", "call_category suhofrukty 0"), new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Мороженое ", "call_category morozhennoe 0") },
            new[]{new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Крупы и мука ", "call_category krupy-i-muka 0"), new Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons.InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(" Консервация ", "call_category konservacija 0") },
        }
};
```

Если нужно могу поделиться готовым проектом тк уже без надобности.

Comment: У вас так и написано в реальном проекте без `using Telegram.Bot.Types`? Как читать такую длинную строку, она же выходит за рамки монитора и приходится туда-сюда скроллить, ведь именно там за рамкой самая существенная часть информации о том, что именно за кнопка.

Comment: Данный пример создает кнопки в 2х столбца поэтому для наглядности один массив с двумя элементами на одной строке. Лично у меня  весь код вмещается без горизонтального скрола)

Comment: > У вас так и написано в реальном проекте без using Telegram.Bot.Types?

Да)

Comment: >Да) -- жесть)))